# MySQL queries run slow in PHP when run as prepared statements in code but run quickly via direct MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, go

A PHP application I’m trying to debug runs several badly designed queries on a bigger MySQL database.

A few pages are really slow and it turned out that it is because of a few queries. I started to check every query one by one and though they are slow they are not that slow on their own.

After some further debugging it turned out that they are only slow when they are being run by the application as prepared statements.

- If I run the query by hand via MySQL client it takes about 300 ms. If I run create a prepared statement via MySQL client and set the parameters and run it, it takes about 300 ms.
- If I run the simple query from PHP (mysqli) it takes about 300 ms.
- If I run it like the application does—via [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)—as prepared statement it takes 100 seconds.

I thought maybe it's `mysqli` so I tried it with PDO, the result is the same. Tried different PHP versions (5.6, 7.2, 7.3) and get the same result.

So I gave a last chance and wrote a small Go script to test, and I get the same results and things improved.

Now if I run the prepared statement version of the query from MySQL client or MySQL Workbench or PHPStorms Database client it's fast. And if I run the query from code it's freaking fast.

Any help would be really appreciated about what should I look after, where should I continue my debugging.

Comment: Check the code to see if it's running the query in a loop. It's not uncommon to see that in poorly coded applications. A 300ms query run 300 times in a loop would take 90 seconds.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with this sadly. I used a pure script what only contains the two version of the query and the measurement of execution time

Comment: Try running the query in both places with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) and see if there are any differences that might cause the issue.

Comment: We have run both queries with EXPLAIN, the execution plans are identical except one of the tables having the `Uses index condition;` Extra on it for the prepared version.
Also the query is executed only once, nothing is in a loop, the only difference is the prepared statement part. There are not an insane number of parameters either (9 in total), they are also simple (5 ints with values of 0, 1 and 2, and 3 short strings). When checking performance it was clear that all the load is in mysql, which maxes out the CPU. For most of the time the query is in `sending data` state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as it turns out, this was caused by a slightly different execution plan. MySQL seems to create the execution plan purely based on the statement, not including the parameter values when using prepared statements via `mysqli` or `PDO` , which kind of makes sense. However when it's provided with the full query, in our case it introduced an optimisation on one of the tables which made a huge difference.

One of the tables (with 5.5 million rows) had the `Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)` Extra on it when running with the non prepared statement, while with the prepared statement it didn't. This seems to have made a close to 1000x performance difference for us.

I am still not sure why this has not an issue via PHPStorm or the CLI `mysql` client, my best guess is, that certain APIs in MySQL expect the execution plan to be complete when a statement is prepared, while other APIs, and the CLI client don't.